# Is there a downside of having SEVERAL ENCODINGS on different pages on the SAME WEBSITE?

Tags: html, encoding

Some historic pages on my website are encoded with `iso-8859-1` while all new pages are encoded with `UTF-8`.

Should i convert the older `iso-8859-1` to `UTF-8`, or there is no problom as long as they have proper headers and declare charset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each page is served and processed separately, using its own character encoding as declared or as inferred by a browser. Any downside with using different encodings would thus be related to the *management* of the site, not to the use of the pages.